# I need help answering this probability question

Tags: probability-distributions

In a pizza takeout restaurant, the following probability distribution was obtained.
The random variable x represents the number of toppings for a large pizza.

[In the image, x is the number of toppings for a large pizza. P(x) is the probability of ordering the number of toppings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCJdg.jpg)

Find the probability that  more than one toppings is ordered.

A. 0.30
B. 0.40
C. 0.70
D. 0.20

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the random variable that represents the number of topics. Then what you are asked to compute is simply $P(X>1)$ which can be simply calculated by$$
P(X>1)=P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)=0.20+0.06+0.04=0.30
$$
and so the answer is A.